# How to Create a Test Cycle Using Zephyr Scale Data Center REST API?

Tags: zephyr-rtos, jira-zephyr

I am working on integrating Zephyr Scale with our Data Center to enhance our testing process through the automation of test result uploads. While I've successfully utilized the REST API to search for created test cases (e.g., using https:///rest/atm/latest/testcase/PZSP-T1),

I'm now aiming to extend this automation further by creating test cycles, adding tests to these cycles, and updating execution statuses.

However, I'm finding it challenging to navigate the API for these specific tasks due to the scarcity of detailed documentation or examples. My efforts to locate comprehensive API documentation for Zephyr Scale Data Center that covers test cycle management have not been fruitful.

Could anyone share insights or resources on how to:

1. Create a test cycle using the Zephyr Scale Data Center REST API.
2. Add tests to a created cycle
3. Update the execution status of these tests within the cycle?

Any guidance, including API endpoint details and payload examples for these actions, would be immensely helpful.

Comment: We can create the test cycle using this URL: 

https://hostname/rest/atm/1.0/testrun

Body:

{
  "name": "Name of the cycle",
  "projectKey": "Key of the project"
}

Comment: I think you might want to retag this as `zephyr-rtos` is quite different than what you are asking about